# Submitting Assignment on Coursera ML in Octave

Tags: machine-learning, submit, octave

**Programming assignment  Week 3, Machine Learning, Andrew-ng, Coursera**
System: Ubuntu 16.04
Octave 4.0.0

**Problem:** Cannot submit the code to the server. This code was successfully submitted from Windows env.

```
octave:1> submit
== Submitting solutions | Logistic Regression...
Login (email address): *************
Token: ************
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100    25  100   958     11    436  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   437
error: structure has no member 'message'
error: called from
    submitWithConfiguration at line 35 column 5
    submit at line 40 column 3
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
error: called from
    submitWithConfiguration at line 35 column 5
    submit at line 40 column 3
```

Comment: as mentioned in the instructor's notes you should use octave version > 4

Comment: use higher version say 4.0.2,

Answer (score 55):

Octave 4.0.0 doesn't work well with submit scripts (on Ubuntu).

Check the version on your terminal:

```
octave --version
```

if it's 4.0.0 update it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install octave
```

There is also warning in the discussions.

Comment: Yeah, it seems problem with version. Thank you it helped.

Comment: Do not use Octave 4.0.0. It has a defect in one of the functions that are used to submit your work. We should NOT be using Octave 3.8.x - it is obsolete and the grader process does not work correctly with certain linux-derived operating systems. More infor at the following thread on Coursera https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/discussions/all/threads/v2YppY8FEeWIeBJxvl1elQ

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to a new version worked in my case. 4.0.0 is not working and giving the error persistently. I installed GNU Octave, version 4.2.1 and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Although [*Vaibhav Pandey*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45976213/) is a sound advice (upgrade to 4.2.x or higher), I believe this specific error message is caused by not explicitly typing in your email address.

The "submit" prompt is a bit misleading, as `Login (email address):` can be misinterpreted as "your email has been stored somewhere as a default", when in fact you have to input it explicitly again.

After some hair pulling on OSX, I solved this:

```
error: structure has no member 'message'
error: called from
    submitWithConfiguration at line 35 column 5
    submit at line 30 column 3
```

by simply explicitly entering my email address.